# MVC4 SimpleMembership Roles / Add field to webpages_Roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to add more properties to the Roles (like a long description for instance).

I would also like to be able to associate a role to given "resource" in my database (like *"Writer on the Sports Section*"). This is similar to what this person asked about: [MVC roles with custom properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991274/mvc-roles-with-custom-properties).

I could use [this](http://blog.spontaneouspublicity.com/including-asp-net-simple-membership-tables-as-part-of-your-entity-framework-model) and map the webpages_Roles table to EF, and add more fields to it, and even relationships to other entities. This would be particularly useful in multi-tenant application that allow each tenant to define their own roles and having each role point to the resources it has access to.

I wonder if this is a supported approach to the issue or if it might break SimpleMembership (I am going to try myself, but I am more interested on knowing if this is a workable approach in the long run and if there are similar experiences out there - maybe a tutorial on extending the Roles).

Specific questions:

1. Is this possible?
2. do you know of a tutorial or another web reference where this is done?

Comment: I'm also quite interested in this, did you manage to get any tests working?

Comment: I added the fields to the webpages_Roles and so far it has been working, but we haven't stress tested it (it is basically in a really small production environment).